# Can I delete some value in my list variable?or Has a better solution?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a project like text scrolling display.It can split to 3 parts. First is program for get the data like color and message and send them out on usb port to RS485. Second is microcontroller and third is moniter that compound from adressable LED.

My problem is in the first part. I use tkinter to make my program and it already work on my target but it has a one thing that i can't solve it.
I need to show a buffer size on my program include warning and delete the over buffer before send the data because my microcontroller has a low memory so that my message must be limited.

### This is my example code for this new part before insert to the main code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
data = len(var.get())
def lenstr():
    global data
    if data > 20:
        print("Over Buffer")
        data = len(var.get())
        M['text'] = data
        root.after(1, lenstr)
    else:
        data = len(var.get())
        M['text'] = data
        root.after(1, lenstr)
l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()
M = Label(root, text="")
M.pack()
t = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
t.pack()
lenstr()
root.mainloop()
```

---

From This code i can show the length of my message and when it more than 20 
it will print Over Buffer.
[1] https://www.img.in.th/image/Ee2lZa : is my result of code

So that next step is write the code in if data > 20 to delete the over buffers
and return the old message before over to show.

Later, I tried to declare a list variable and send value to it and i will use method pop() or remove() but it can't because both can't define position i want(My data form like this  list['ABCDEFG'] and i want to delete [0][6] )

Can i delete some value from my list variable or it has a better solution to solve my problem?

sorry for my weakness english and thank you for reading or reply it.

I used list variable because i thougth that both method like remove() and pop() can solve my problem.
I tried to set variable from list and it can work like this code
and i can set new value to show.In this code when it over buffer it will set value to Google

### [2] https://www.img.in.th/image/EeGfiQ : result of this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
var = StringVar()
data = len(var.get())
LABELTEST = ['Google','Facebook']
def lenstr():
    global data
    if data > 20:
        print("Over Buffer")
        data = len(var.get())
        var.set(LABELTEST[0])
        print(var.get())
        M['text'] = data
        root.after(1, lenstr)
    else:
        data = len(var.get())
        M['text'] = data
        root.after(1, lenstr)


l = Label(root, textvariable = var)
l.pack()
M = Label(root, text="")
M.pack()
t = Entry(root, textvariable = var)
t.pack()
lenstr()
root.mainloop()
```

---

Comment: You can delete from a list using the delete keyword, you can also index to only get the length of characters you want. The format is `list_var[start:end]` so if you want to get just the first 20 elements you could do `list_var[:20]`.

Comment: Thank you very much